# Why isn't overloading with a different generic type as a parameter allowed?

Tags: java, generics, overloading

Why isn't overloading with a different generic type as a parameter allowed in Java?

For example,

```
private static String convertListToString(List<Character> list)
```

and

```
private static String convertListToString(List<String> list) {
```

causes an error. 
Why does Java does this and are there any safe and popular workarounds?

**Related**

Does exactly what I need, but in a different language - [Overloading a method that takes a generic list with different types as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926801/overloading-a-method-that-takes-a-generic-list-with-different-types-as-a-paramet)

Comment: because generic types are erased at compile time: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: what do you want to do inside that method?

Comment: @Deadpool convert the given list to a string

Comment: may be if you are open to suggestion you can use `String.join` method instead of all this code @Marvin

Comment: @Deadpool Thank you, but I have other methods like these

Comment: @Deadpool this does not work for characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Themelis stated, you cannot do that because they are fundamentally the same parameter. However, you can get around this by utilizing the generics like so:

```java
private static <T> String convertListToString(List<T> list) {
    // Your code here.
}
```

Inside of the method body, you could then loop through and call the toString method on the generics.

```java
String s = "";

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    s += list.get(i).toString();
}

return s;
```

Answer (score 1):

Overloading a method happens when you use the same name but change the parameters.

I am sure you are familiar with that, for example:

```java
    void myMethod(int something){
        // implementation
    }

    void myMethod(int something, String somethingElse){
        // implementation
    }
```

In your case `List<String>` is not a different type of parameter than `List<Character>`. The generic class is defined as:

```java
List<T>{
  // class implementation, a list that manages objects of type 'T'
}
```

### Edit

To *get around this* create a generic method where every list of a type (`List<T>`) gets converted to `String`. Every `Object` has a `toString()` method!

```java
    static <T> String convertToString(List<T> list){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // assuming list is not null of course
        for (T item : list) {
            sb.append(item.toString());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: This is not correct. At `runtime`, there're no generics - only `Object`!

Comment: Ok at runtime the `List<T>` becomes apparently `List<String>`, `List<Character>` or any `Object`, no one said no to that...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **NO**.

Generics types i.e. `Character` and `String` in your example exist only at compile time.

At runtime, `List<Character>` and `List<String>` become to `List<Object>`. Java knows about it and avoids this situation giving you compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer: That's what the spec says. The *erased type* is used for overload resolution.

Note, this is a *compile-time* issue.

There's no fundamental reason that the specs could not have been written to add generic information to overloading without adding runtime generic type information to objects. However, that would add more complication to the overload rules, and the backward-compatibility story with old code using raw types would not have been as good.

Generally it's a good idea to prefer not overloading methods. Choose a more descriptive name, and if the name is particularly difficult, perhaps the methods are misguided.